# Как создать двумерный динамический массив в котором элементом будет массив символов char?

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

хочу создать двумерный динамический массив в котором элементом будет массив символов char (тоже динамический)... как это реализовать ?

```
void making_an_array(int**&p_arr, int const rows, int const cols)
{
    p_arr = new int*[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        p_arr[i] = new int[cols];
}
```

вот функция создает двумерный массив int а в моей элемент будет char...
как быть?

```
void create_a_string_element()
{
    int symbol_number{};
    int string_size = rand() % 5 + 5;
    char *string_element = new char[string_size + 1];

    for (int j = 0; j <= string_size; j++)
    {
        symbol_number = rand() % 32 + 192;
        if (j == string_size)
            string_element[j] = '\0';
        else
            string_element[j] = symbol_number;
    }

    delete[]string_element;
}
```

а тут я создаю свой элемент.
Занимаюсь самообразованием

Comment: Вам надо изначально создавать указатель на указатель. То есть char** string_element. А уже потом указателю на указатель присваивать указатель на чаровский динамический массив

Comment: `Int first, second;
fd = new char**[first];
for(int i = 0; i<first; i++)
   fd[i] = new char*[second];` Не гарантирую точный синтаксис, написал на скорую руку на телефоне

Comment: first, second это что? rows,cols как в моей функции ... это то же что и у меня ... это просто двумерный массив... размер char[???] неизвестен ... он определяется в самой функции...

Comment: А какая разница, где определять: в функции или нет? Вы можете передавать как параметр в функцию и в функции его создавать. Вы можете генерировать размер произвольно. Сути это не меняет

Comment: а теперь в цикле second присвоить fd[i]= мой char элемент из моей функции? я правильно понимаю?

Comment: fd[first][second] = ..., Где first и second - в данном случае счетчикт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int first, second;
fd = new char**[first];
for(int i = 0; i<first; i++)
   fd[i] = new char*[second];

for(int i = 0; i<first; i++)
   for(int j = 0; j<second; j++)
      fd[i, j] = ...
```

На скорую руку это выглядит как-то так

Comment: int first, second;
fd = new char**[first];
for(int i = 0; i<first; i++)
   fd[i] = new char*[second]; for(int j = 0; j<second; j++)
      fd[i, j] = ...

Comment: В чем вопрос?..

Comment: все получилось спасибо!

Comment: void making_an_array(char***&arr, int const rows, int const cols)
{
 char*string_element;
 arr = new char**[rows];
 for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  arr[i] = new char*[cols];
  for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
   create_a_string_element(string_element);
   arr[i][j] = string_element;
  }
  
 }
}

Comment: Не забудьте в конце освобождать память из под массива

Comment: `[i, j]` -> `[i][j]`